# Synching Bootstrap 4 Carousel with animated text (morphext)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I made a hero section with a bootstrap 4 carousel and some animated text using morphext. They are supposed to cycle at the same time.

I have tweaked the intervals on both of them manually and right now it kind of works, however sometimes they will fall out of synch if the page takes longer to load for example.

Here is my html:

```
<!-- /// HERO SECTION /// -->
<div id="hero-section" class="small-margin">
    <div class="row hero-unit">
        <div class="col-md-5">
            <div class="hero-caption"><!-- Main Tagline -->
                <h1>WE MAKE <br> <span id="moving-text" class="colored">AWESOME, BEAUTIFUL, EPIC</span> <br> GAMES <br></h1>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-7">
            <div id="hero-slider" class="carousel slide carousel-fade" data-ride="carousel">
                <div class="carousel-inner">
                    <div class="carousel-item active">
                        <img src="https://imgur.com/5Gjknuf.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="img">
                    </div>
                    <div class="carousel-item">
                      <img src="https://imgur.com/KSC44FR.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="img">
                    </div>
                    <div class="carousel-item">
                      <img src="https://imgur.com/6pqwyXu.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="img">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div><!-- Hero Section End -->
```

Here is a fiddle with the full code: https://jsfiddle.net/vn2aboeh/

Is there a way to sych up the text with the carousel using javascript / jquery?

Thanks

Comment: Probably because the get initiated at different times and plus the speed of the actual animation is most likely different from the morphtext "fadeDown" and the carousels fade transition. Why don't you try triggering your morphtext using the `slide.bs.carousel` [event of the carousel](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/carousel/#events)?

Comment: This works for synching them up however it makes the animated text appear on screen all at once until the carousel triggers. (here is the updated fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/ktfo4puy/)
So morphext would have to be triggered first on page load followed by the carousel..any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's your HTML. Remove `data-ride="carousel"`

So this:

```
<!-- /// HERO SECTION /// -->
    <div id="hero-section" class="small-margin">
        <div class="row hero-unit">
            <div class="col-md-5">
                <div class="hero-caption"><!-- Main Tagline -->
                    <h1>WE MAKE <br> <span id="moving-text" class="colored">AWESOME, BEAUTIFUL, EPIC</span> <br> GAMES <br></h1>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-7">
                <div id="hero-slider" class="carousel slide carousel-fade">
                    <div class="carousel-inner">
                        <div class="carousel-item active">
                            <img src="https://imgur.com/5Gjknuf.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="img">
                        </div>
                        <div class="carousel-item">
                          <img src="https://imgur.com/KSC44FR.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="img">
                        </div>
                        <div class="carousel-item">
                          <img src="https://imgur.com/6pqwyXu.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="img">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div><!-- Hero Section End -->
```

This is from the Bootstrap documentation:

> The data-ride="carousel" attribute is used to mark a carousel as
>   animating starting at page load. It cannot be used in combination with
>   (redundant and unnecessary) explicit JavaScript initialization of the
>   same carousel.

Answer (score 0):

Ok i found a solution, here is the code I arrived at:

```
 $("#moving-text").Morphext({
    animation: "fadeInDown",
    separator: ",",
    speed: 4000,
    //After text animation is complete, initiate carousel
    complete: function () {
        $("#hero-slider").carousel("next")
    }
});
```

It triggers the carousel after the text has finished animating.